# Java 8: How can I use a static method as a parameter for another method?

Tags: java, lambda, syntax, java-8

My situation:

```
class Test {
    private static void xxx(String s) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    private static void yyy(Consumer<String> f) {
        try {
            f.apply('hello');
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])() {
        yyy(xxx);  // <-- not working!!
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to pass a static method as a parameter for another static method. I think that the correct way to declare the signature of the method `yyy` is with `Consumer`, but I'm not really sure about the other part, passing `xxx` as the parameter.

A possible solution I've found is to write

```
yyyy(s -> xxx(s));
```

But it looks ugly and it doesn't really work if `xxx` throws exceptions.

By using

```
yyy(Test::xxx);
```

I got this error

```
error: incompatible thrown types SQLException in method reference
```

Comment: A correct reference to a static member (field, method, nested class...) should include the class's name. Thus `Test::xxx`, not `xxx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a method reference:

```
class Test {
    private static void xxx(String s) {
        //do something with string
    }
    private static void yyy(Consumer<String> c) {
        c.accept("hello");
    }
    public static void zzz() {
        yyy(Test::xxx);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! There was an additional details I was trying to use, I may edit the question. If xxx throws an exception, should I change the declaration of _Consumer_? Because it still gives me an error because of that.

Comment: @heapOverflow if you throw an unchecked exception, you will avoid that error.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case it's a checked exception (SQLException) so it's not really my choice. Of course I could try catch but I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: Then make it your choice. Stop using a method that throws a checked exception and use a method that only throws unchecked exceptions instead. Hint: it's possible to write by yourself your own methods, such as writing a new method that calls a preexisting method.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code

```
class Test {
    private static Consumer<String>  xxx(String s) {
        //do something with string
        return null;// return Consumer for now passing null
    }

    private static void yyy(Consumer<String> f) {
        //do something with Consumer
    }

    public static void zzz(){
        yyy(xxx("hello")); 
    }
}
```